# How can I randomly pick a number between given numbers in js?

Tags: javascript

So let's say I have specific numbers for `x` such as `470`, `240`, `680`.

I want to pick randomly from those three. How could I do this?

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment? What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071573/is-there-a-simple-way-to-make-a-random-selection-from-an-array-in-javascript-or